# Best method to make an icon for web and phone application

Tags: icons

I want to make an icon for both my website and phone application. So what is the best way? using adobe illustrator or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think that Gimp seems the most reasonable option, as it is available for free. The web is full of tutorials for it, so I think it's worth searching there. For example: [Creating Icons](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Creating_Icons/)

Answer (score 0):

Using a vector graphics application like Adobe Illustrator would be the best way to go, although if you've not used it before you have to invest some time getting familiar with the tools such as Bezier curves.  If you're an iPad user I recommend iDraw, a vector illustration tool for the IOS. It's easier to use than illustrator and allows you to prototype graphics at the correct screen resolution on the retina screen.  If you're designing for IOS then I suggest looking at [Apples guidance material](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html) on the correct image resolutions to use.